# Docker build stuck at step 8/9

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to deploy my model to tensorflow serving. for that i'm creating docker image by using the steps from the following link https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-part-2-containerize-it-db0ad7ca35a7 . While creating the docker image the build stops at step 8/9.

Below is the commandline screen

```
~/serving$ docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.239 GB
Step 1/9 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:e27e9d7f7f28d67aa9e2d7540bdc2b33254b452ee8e60f388875e5b7d9b2b696
Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 0458a4468cbc
Step 2/9 : MAINTAINER Jeremiah Harmsen <jeremiah@google.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7bada30b20fe
Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y         build-essential         curl         git         libfreetype6-dev         libpng12-dev         libzmq3-dev         mlocate         pkg-config         python-dev         python-numpy         python-pip         software-properties-common         swig         zip         zlib1g-dev         libcurl3-dev         openjdk-8-jdk        openjdk-8-jre-headless         wget         &&     apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57f9ee7ab8cb
Step 4/9 : RUN pip install mock grpcio
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 46db62fe343f
Step 5/9 : ENV BAZELRC /root/.bazelrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4e1be28c3a58
Step 6/9 : ENV BAZEL_VERSION 0.5.4
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 22d8de897aa6
Step 7/9 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fd083766a738
Step 8/9 : RUN mkdir /bazel &&     cd /bazel &&     curl -fSsL -O https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/$BAZEL_VERSION/bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh &&     curl -fSsL -o /bazel/LICENSE.txt https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bazelbuild/bazel/master/LICENSE &&     chmod +x bazel-*.sh &&     ./bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh &&     cd / &&     rm -f /bazel/bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
 ---> Running in 24465785bb05
```

Comment: What happens if you run those commands by hand?

Comment: When im trying all commands from the Dockerfile.devel , the commands for setting up bazel are not working

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question. I tried to run the commands by hand myself and noticed a long delay downloading the installer since it's 185M in size. How long did you wait for step 8 to complete?

Comment: First it takes around 1 minute for sending the build contents to docker daemon and in just seconds it goes to step 8/9  and gets stuck showing running in (some id).

Comment: That's not an answer to that question either. Not sure how I can help you without knowing either of these.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to update the BASEL_VERSION in the docker file to the present version number. You can get the file at tensorflow_serving/tools/docker

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by commenting out the Bazel build commands in the Dockerfile.devel file, and then running the same Bazel commands one by one afterwards.

1. Comment out the Bazel build commands in the Dockerfile.devel file
2. docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
3. At this point, the docker container should be able to finish building.
   While inside the container, run the following commands to install Bazel.

   mkdir /bazel

   cd /bazel

   curl -fSsL -O https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/$BAZEL_VERSION/bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

   chmod +x bazel-*.sh

   ./bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh